# Face identification with opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, video, computer-vision

I'm using the libraries OpenCV for image processing in C + + and this is my question: can you think possible to do a facial recognition (saying the name of a person based on a database of photos) by comparing the frame of videocamera with images in a database using the technique of image histograms comparison? (Note that i compare only the facial region of an image using an example included in the opecv libraries).

I'm asking this because i've just tried to do a program like above but i have a lot of problem (often i detect the wrong person)

Comment: If you find a way, let me know. You are facing a super challenging problem. What if the camera points to the person from a side? Or little above? Or from below? What if they wear a glasses and take them off? etc

Comment: I'm supposing that the camera points to the same side with which the photos was taken

Comment: Still, if they turn around, the image is not the same

Comment: Can you suggest me a good way to compare people's faces?

Comment: No, not really, otherwise I would write an answer :( You can try with a histogram of different regions in the image.

Comment: Facial recognition is *really, really hard.*  I doubt very much that there will be anywhere near enough information in a histogram to do anything sensible.

Comment: Also, lighting, color, contrast, and focus add to the complexity.  Image resolution (pixel density) adds to the work involved.  Simple image recognition is very difficult, nonetheless image recognition.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to start with compiling the [Face Detection using OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) example.  As others have pointed out, general facial recognition isn't exactly an easy problem to solve.  [EigenFaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) is one common technique for face recognition that is fairly easy to understand and implement.

As others have stated, it's a hard problem, but this gives you a place to start.

Comment: I've yet used that piece of code in my program! My problem is not the face recognition but the comparison of the face for people recognition

Comment: I believe the Eigenfaces concept should be used. Use OpenCV to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of both the face in the frame and the photos in database. If they are the same then the eigenvalues should have a correlation of close to 1. Or you could find the Euclidean distance between the eigenvectors - they should be equidistant. Also reading up on Principal Component Analysis (PCA) should help. Do post your final solution here.

Answer (score 7):

Some method I had experience with them are

- [metric learning](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00439290) for comparing faces
- [naming video characters](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/): they use SIFT descriptors computed at specific feducial points on each face. Their code worked quite well for me in the past.

A dataset and benchmark that is dedicated for this task is [labeled faces in the wild](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/). You can find there references to working methods for comparing faces after detection.

**UPDATE:**
I have a description of an experiment on face clustering: unsupervised face identification.
The experiment is described in [Section 4.4 of my thesis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7362v2.pdf).
The basic flow is as follows

1. **Metric learning:** how to determine if two faces are of the same person or not.
   This part is supervised, in the sense that it requires as input face images labeled with the identity of the person who appears in each photo.

   a. Detect fiducial points (eyes, corner of mouth, nose).
     You may use [this code](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/), or more recent versions such as [this one](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/).

   b. Extract SIFT descriptors at the detected fiducial points.

   c. Construct a "face descriptor": each face is described using a **single** vector.
   This vector is a concatenation of the **`sqrt`** of all the SIFT descriptors.

   d. Use the method described [here](http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00439290) to learn a mahalanobis distance between faces of different persons.
2. **Unsupervised face identification:** Once a metric was learned, you may use new photos of **new** people (these people need not be part of the training set, you may use photos of **unseen-before** people!).

   a. Repeat stages a-c to construct the same "face descriptor" vector for each input face.

   b. Compare the descriptor vectors using the learned mahalanobis distance.

Comment: A thesis-based answer! So you've done some research in this field. Thanks for sharing your findings.

Comment: @IwanKelaiah thanks. I hope you'll find it useful. I have some relevant Matlab code on [my web page](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an existing algorithm such as the one available in the Luxand FaceSDK: http://www.luxand.com/facesdk/ rather than trying to develop your own.

Answer (score 0):

there are 3 builtin techniques for face-recognition in opencv now, pca(eigenfaces), lda(fisherfaces) and lbph.

nice example code:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/facerec_demo.cpp