# OpenCV how can i detect webcam and compare the local file to match face

Tags: java, c++, c, opencv

The highlighted code demonstrate openCV framework is loaded in my C code and it render Police watching. Which is just to demonstrate it works very smooth and very clean code to write.

**Target:** 
My webCAM is connected in to the USB port. I would like to capture the live webcam image and match from a local file (/tmp/myface.png), if live webcam match with local file myface.png, it will show the text "Police watching"

**My Questions to fix:**
1) How can i now, capture my webCAM on this following code? 
2) When the webCAM is captured, how can i load the file and find if it match, on match it shows that text only.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main() 
{
    CvPoint pt   = cvPoint( 620/4, 440/2 ); // width, height
    IplImage* hw = cvCreateImage(cvSize(620, 440), 8,3);  // width, height             
    CvFont font; // cvSet(hw,cvScalar(0,0,0)); // optional
    cvInitFont (&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1, CV_AA);
    cvPutText  (hw, "Police watching", pt, &font, CV_RGB(150, 0, 150));        
    cvShowImage("Police watching", hw);     //cvNamedWindow("Police watching", 0); // optional
    cvWaitKey  (0);
}
```

Note: When this model will work i will practice this to convert in to JNI java model.

Comment: possible duplicate of [People detection with opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597302/people-detection-with-opencv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing a video frame is simple just [follow this example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture). The essential part is:

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
while ( 1 ) {
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    //match(img,frame);
}
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
```

The second part is probably much harder and depends on what exactly are you trying to do. If you want to simply compare images, you can use [cvNorm](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#norm). If you want [face detection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) or face recognition you really need to know what are you doing.

Comment: Tried your first simple example but it fails to detect the webCAM: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
ERROR: frame is null...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get a webcam feed... (the code is in Python but is easily translated)

```
# create capture device
device = 0 # assume we want first device
capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)    

# check if capture device is OK
if not capture:
    print "Error opening capture device"
    sys.exit(1)

# capture the current frame
frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

if frame is None:
    break
    # mirror

cv.Flip(frame, None, 1)   

#Do face detection here
```

I think you'll have an incredibly hard time trying to match a face from a single file to a live video stream.  Look into cv.HaarDetectObjects for some cool feature detection algorithms.